# Large concurrent user performance issues for Apache + mod_jk + GlassFish v3.1 clusters

Tags: apache-2.2, glassfish, mod-jk

I am running a java ee 6 ear application on a GlassFish v3.1 ( 2 clusters with 2 instances each) load balanced by an Apache v2.2 with mod_jk - all on the same server (Windows Server 2003 R2, Intel Xeon CPU x5670 @2.93Ghz, 6GB RAM, 2 cpus).

The web application is accessed by around ~100 users. When they all try to access it at the same time every morning ~8am, the response is very slow while trying to access the main jsf home page.

Apart from that I have seen the CPU usage spike upto 99% by the httpd process during the day frequently and I start seeing errors in the mod_jk.log file.

```
[Wed Jun 08 08:25:43 2011] [9380:8216] [info] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (1885): Writing to client aborted or client network problems
[Wed Jun 08 08:25:43 2011] [9380:8216] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2543): (myAppLocalInstance4) sending request to tomcat failed (unrecoverable), because of client write error (attempt=1)
```

Any suggestions on how I can go about improving this?

Apache configuration is mostly the default as shown below

```
ServerRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2"

Listen 80

LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>


<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>


LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
JkMount /myApp/* loadbalancerLocal
JkMount /myAppRemote/* loadbalancerRemote
JkMount /myApp loadbalancerLocal
JkMount /myAppRemote loadbalancerRemote
```

The workers.properties config file is:

```
worker.list=loadbalancerLocal,loadbalancerRemote

worker.myAppLocalInstance1.type=ajp13
worker.myAppLocalInstance1.host=localhost
worker.myAppLocalInstance1.port=8109
worker.myAppLocalInstance1.lbfactor=1
worker.myAppLocalInstance1.socket_keepalive=1
worker.myAppLocalInstance1.socket_timeout=1000

worker.myAppLocalInstance2.type=ajp13
worker.myAppLocalInstance2.host=localhost
worker.myAppLocalInstance2.port=8209
worker.myAppLocalInstance2.lbfactor=1
worker.myAppLocalInstance2.socket_keepalive=1
worker.myAppLocalInstance2.socket_timeout=1000

worker.myAppLocalInstance3.type=ajp13
worker.myAppLocalInstance3.host=localhost
worker.myAppLocalInstance3.port=8309
worker.myAppLocalInstance3.lbfactor=1
worker.myAppLocalInstance3.socket_keepalive=1
worker.myAppLocalInstance3.socket_timeout=1000

worker.myAppLocalInstance4.type=ajp13
worker.myAppLocalInstance4.host=localhost
worker.myAppLocalInstance4.port=8409
worker.myAppLocalInstance4.lbfactor=1
worker.myAppLocalInstance4.socket_keepalive=1
worker.myAppLocalInstance4.socket_timeout=1000

worker.myAppRemoteInstance1.type=ajp13
worker.myAppRemoteInstance1.host=localhost
worker.myAppRemoteInstance1.port=8509
worker.myAppRemoteInstance1.lbfactor=1
worker.myAppRemoteInstance1.socket_keepalive=1
worker.myAppRemoteInstance1.socket_timeout=1000

worker.myAppRemoteInstance2.type=ajp13
worker.myAppRemoteInstance2.host=localhost
worker.myAppRemoteInstance2.port=8609
worker.myAppRemoteInstance2.lbfactor=1
worker.myAppRemoteInstance2.socket_keepalive=1
worker.myAppRemoteInstance2.socket_timeout=1000

worker.myAppRemoteInstance3.type=ajp13
worker.myAppRemoteInstance3.host=localhost
worker.myAppRemoteInstance3.port=8709
worker.myAppRemoteInstance3.lbfactor=1
worker.myAppRemoteInstance3.socket_keepalive=1
worker.myAppRemoteInstance3.socket_timeout=1000

worker.myAppRemoteInstance4.type=ajp13
worker.myAppRemoteInstance4.host=localhost
worker.myAppRemoteInstance4.port=8809
worker.myAppRemoteInstance4.lbfactor=1
worker.myAppRemoteInstance4.socket_keepalive=1
worker.myAppRemoteInstance4.socket_timeout=1000

worker.loadbalancerLocal.type=lb
worker.loadbalancerLocal.sticky_session=True
worker.loadbalancerLocal.balance_workers=myAppLocalInstance1,myAppLocalInstance2,myAppLocalInstance3,myAppLocalInstance4
worker.loadbalancerRemote.type=lb
worker.loadbalancerRemote.balance_workers=myAppRemoteInstance1,myAppRemoteInstance2,myAppRemoteInstance3,myAppRemoteInstance4
worker.loadbalancerRemote.sticky_session=True
```

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering why you run so many instances on the same machine, but I guess you have loadtested this setup and found it to be delivering the highest performance. Also, since there is no mentioning of the backend of the EAR (database ?), let's assume that there is no problem here.

I would therefore approach this irrelevant of the glassfish / mod_jk setup. Check what is actually happening, when 100 users access the same page. How many parallel connections are being opened by the clients, how does it relate to Apache's MaxClients? Are the static resources being cached by the clients; are you sending Etag / Last-Modified / Cache-Control headers? Can you reduce the number of requests (check out the page with [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/))?

Next, get the static resources delivered by Apache, not by the Glassfish appservers. This will relieve the appservers and the loadbalancer and free up slots for actual dynamic page creation. To do this, extract the CSS/JS files and images from the EAR and place them into the document root of apache in a directory (e.g. `/static/`). Then make sure the clients request the resources that way, or use the `RewriteEngine` to map the requests accordingly.

If page creation is expensive but the result is reasonably cacheable, you could consider placing an instance of [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) in front of the Apache proxy. You need to have the cache headers under control first though.

Good luck!